# Field args rejected when return a function not object

Tags: javascript, graphql, graphql-js

I want ask about **GraphQL**
This code will be failed, and shows error

> Error: Mutation.addUser args must be an object with argument names as keys.

here is the code

```
const Schema = new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: "Mutation",
  description: "Mutation schema",
  fields() {
    return {
      // Add user
      addUser: {
        type: UserSchema,
        args: () => {
          return {
            firstName: {
             type: GraphQLString
            }
          };
        },
        resolve(_, args){
          return Db.models.user.update( () => {
            return _.mapValues(args, (v, k) => {
              return args[k];
            });
          }, {
            returning: true
          });
        }
      }

    };
  }
});
```

But, this code work perfectly

```
const Schema = new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: "Mutation",
  description: "Mutation schema",
  fields() {
    return {
      // Add user
      addUser: {
        type: UserSchema,
        args: {
          firstName: {
            type: GraphQLString
          },
          lastName: {
            type: GraphQLString
          }
        },
        resolve(_, args){
          return Db.models.user.update( () => {
            return _.mapValues(args, (v, k) => {
              return args[k];
            });
          }, {
            returning: true
          });
        }
      }

    };
  }
});
```

Why `args` can't return object from function?

Answer (score 0):

The `fields` itself can be a function, so having another function inside it to define args is kind of redundant.

The purpose of having them as functions is to be able to define types that need to refer to each other, or types that need to refer to themselves in a field.

So having only `fields` as a function will do the trick.

Comment: can you give me an example to implements this?

Comment: @HabibRohman for which part do you need an example? in the code you have posted, the `fields` itself is a function.